# Unified way of closing a browser window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Is there a way to simply close a browser window, *guaranteed*? Last time I heard, calling `window.close()` or `self.close()` only works when the current window is launched from another window. Is there a way to get the majority of browsers to close the current window when this isn't so?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: User finishes taking survey, they don't want or need the window any more, offer them an easy way to close it. Project requirement.

Comment: Open the survey in a popup then.  You will have no issues closing it and you won't interfere with the users browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to close a parent window via script without prompting in any major browser.

So nope, no guarantees.  On a child window, `window.close` and `self.close` both work great.

Comment: How can I close it _with prompting_? At this point, I'd just like to close it in any way possible :)

Comment: The standard ways (window.close and self.close) used to throw prompts in IE however testing in latest browsers shows this to not work.  Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/NEF9R/  You may be out of luck unless there is a different method.   In theory it used to be possible to close the parent from a child via window.opener.close() however unless I'm mistaken I believe that's been nullified as well.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the quick answer, though :)

Answer (score 1):

in firefox you can't close the window that the user opened you can just close the window you opened firefox not allow that because of security reasons 
take a look at this:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/749393

however that's work with IE

hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (Working in Chrome & IE) -

```
function closeWindow() { 
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
}
```